# Weird notification icon on Adium icon

Tags: icons, adium

What's the meaning of this icon that appears over the adium icon?

[image: adium on the dock]

It looks like corners of a black square (or four triangles) spinning around a circle.

What's it trying to say?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Inside the Adium.app bundle, that icon (and two more like it, with the black square rotated) are called Connect1.png, Connect2.png, and Connect3.png. I'm guessing it means Adium is having trouble connecting to a chat service.

Comment: This makes sense, thanks. My Adium was showing this all the time, which was annoying. Only after reading your answer did I realise that I had an account set up which wasn't valid - disabling this account (under Adium's File/<the account>/Disable) made the spinning circlesquare go away. Thanks!